# Hints on how to calculate $A^{99}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

\begin{equation}
A=\frac{1}{3} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1    & 2    & 2  \\
    2     & -1   & 2  \\
    2     & 2    & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{equation}
$A$ is orthogonal.

Calculate $A^{99}$.

I have no idea how to start. The course book doesn't say anything about matrix to the power of 99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Compute explicitely $A,A^2,A^3$ and $A^4$, can you recognize a pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A is perpendicular to itself!

Since
$$A^2=I$$

You may write

$$A^{99}=A^{98}*A=I^\frac{98}2 A=A$$